# How to create a shortcut in Windows 10 pointing to All Apps screen?

Tags: windows-10

Does anybody knows how to make a desktop shortcut which will take to the all apps screen in windows 10. What command should be written in target of a shortcut? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The target should be: `shell:AppsFolder` quick and easy.

You can use `cmd /c "start shell:AppsFolder"` as the target if explorer complains

Comment: it doesn't work!!

Comment: @Vladimir try again now

Comment: well thank you, now it opens applications folder in traditional desktop mode. What i need is to make it open start menu -> all apps instead.

Comment: For instance, I know how to create a shortcut which will open Windows 10 Search: - **C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{2559a1f8-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}**  goes into target field of the shortcut

Comment: @Vladimir that *is* the start menu > all apps folder.

Comment: I've tested once again, in _Windows 10_ **doesn't** work!

Comment: @Vladimir it *does* work in Windows 10. seriously, try the `cmd` text